# Extracting part of a Numpy column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
>> print(x)

+-----+-----+-----+
|   0 |   1 |   2 |
|-----+-----+-----|
|   1 |   1 |   2 |
|   1 |   1 |   2 |
|   1 |   2 |   1 |
|   1 |   5 |   4 |
|   1 |   7 |   4 |
|   1 |   7 |   4 |
|   1 |   7 |   4 |
|   1 |  12 |   1 |
```

I want to extract the parts of the 2nd columns grouped on a column 1 grouping. After wards the grouped column will be transposed into its own row and coverted to the table below:

```
>> print(x_transformed)

+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|   0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----|
|   1 |   1 | 2   |  2  |  0  |
|   1 |   2 | 1   |  0  |  0  |
|   1 |   5 | 4   |  0  |  0  |
|   1 |   7 | 4   |  4  |  4  |
|   1 |  12 | 1   |  0  |  0  |
```

0's will be inserted in places where there are no values.

- For example if you look at Table 1 in column 1, where we have 7's. The corresponding values in column 2 are 4,4,4. Hence in x_transformed, the horizontal values are 4 , 4, 4

Is there a numpy standard way of doing this? Should I look at Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged your question with "Pandas", so here is a Pandas solution:

```
In [7]: df.pivot_table(index=['0','1'], columns=df.groupby(['0','1']).cumcount()+2, values='2', fill_value=0).reset_index()
Out[7]:
   0   1  2  3  4
0  1   1  2  2  0
1  1   2  1  0  0
2  1   5  4  0  0
3  1   7  4  4  4
4  1  12  1  0  0
```

assuming you have the following columns:

```
In [8]: df.columns
Out[8]: Index(['0', '1', '2'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: You need to answer more of NumPy tagged ones! ;) Happy new year BTW!

Comment: Thank you @Divakar, i'll try, but i still have to learn A LOT !  ;) I wish you a happy new year !!!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> df['c'] = df.groupby('1').cumcount()
>>> df.set_index(['0', '1', 'c'], inplace=True)
>>> df.unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
   0   1  2      
c         0  1  2
0  1   1  2  2  0
1  1   2  1  0  0
2  1   5  4  0  0
3  1   7  4  4  4
4  1  12  1  0  0
```